# searching a string in PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I try to search for words in pdf file and copy the file into directory. Then if the word is there in the pdf the pdf file should moving into directory. the code is working but the file show there is something wrong

```
System.out.println("Enter word you want to search:");
int count2=0;
while(scanner1.hasNext()) {
String SearchWord2= scanner1.next(); 
if(SearchWord2.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
  break;
}





 try {
    File data=new File("C:\\Users\\user012\\Desktop\\Evalution.pdf");
    fileR=new FileReader(data);
    BufferedReader bufferR=new BufferedReader(fileR);

      while((string=bufferR.readLine())!=null) {
          if(string.contains(SearchWord2)) {
          listWord.add(SearchWord2);
          for(String word:listWord) {
               if(set.add(word)==true) {
          System.out.println("Yes, "+word+" is in the file");
        Path temp =  Files.copy(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user012\\Desktop\\Evalution.pdf"),Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user012\\Desktop\\Search\\Evalution2.pdf"));
         
          if(temp != null) {
             System.out.println("File moved successfully.");
     }

          
    
        }}
          
          
          }
          

      
      else {
    

      System.out.println("No, "+SearchWord2+" is Not in the file");
    
 }}}




          
     
         catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
             }catch(IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
          }
          finally {
              fileR.close();
          }}
```

The code working but the pdf file showing something wrong.

Comment: *The code working but the pdf file showing something wrong.* can you explain what this means?

Comment: Please reformat your code and post it again

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries that you can use to achieve this. One of them is PDFBox.

This is how you read from a PDF file. Hopefully this could help.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PdfToConsole {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

      //Loading an existing document
      File file = new File("D://Sample.pdf");
      PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

      //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
      PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

      //Retrieving text from PDF document
      String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
      System.out.println(text);

      //Closing the document
      document.close();
   }
}
```

Here is the [source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-data-from-pdf-file-and-display-on-console-in-java#)

You could then treat it like any other file afterwards.